# Serial connection update line with response

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, newline

I have a Serial connection to a device and am having trouble handling the response from the device.

If I use Hyperterminal and send the command `TIME` to the device, I get a response along the lines of;

```
TIME:13:30:30
```

which will keep updating on the same line. When I try and do this with my app, depending on whether I'm using a RTB or a TB to display the response, I get either;

RTB;

```
TIME:13:30:30
TIME:13:30:31
TIME:13:30:32
TIME:13:30:33
TIME:13:30:34
```

or TB;

```
TIME:13:30:30TIME:13:30:31TIME:13:30:32TIME:13:30:33TIME:13:30:34
```

Code is;

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting()) 
End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        RichTextBox1.AppendText([text])
        TextBox1.AppendText([text])
    End If
End Sub
```

Any way I can get the same response I get when using Hyperterminal?

Comment: Use String.Replace() to convert vbLf to vbCrLf.

Comment: Hi @Jonny, do you have any feedback on my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to accumulate data into a `StringBuilder` until you receive an event that contains the field separator.  Then cut the `StringBuilder` in two at the field separator, set all of the data before the separator into the Text property of the message box, and then continue processing.  Something like this should do (pseudocode follows)

```
StringBuilder builder;

SerialPort1_DataReceived()
    receivedData = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
    builder.Append(receivedData)

    if receivedData contains delimiter
        timeData = builder.ToString().Split(delimiter)
        ReceivedText(timedata[0])
        builder = new StringBuilder(timedata[1])
    end
end
```

So we read each dispatch from the serial port into our buffer.  If we notice that it contains the indicator that a new time value is starting, we split on the indicator, set the text box to contain the beginning of the buffer, and clear the buffer and re-insert the rest.

And in ReceivedText, you would change

```
RichTextBox1.AppendText([text])
```

to

```
RichTextBox1.Text = [text]
```

Apologies for the lack of VB.NET code, I'm quite rusty on the language so this will probably be easier to understand.  Let me know if you have any questions, or if this works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Insure your textBox (TB) has

```
textBox1.Multiline = True 
textBox1.AcceptsReturn = True
```

As a TB is often used for input, a return may instead of being displayed, is used to signal user input completion.

---

Less likely avenue of pursuit.

The incoming data `TIME:13:30:30` has an EOLine, either a CR, LF or CR+LF.  `ReadExisting()` appears to not have any trouble with the incoming data, hence this is not likely a serial data issue, other than an extra/unexpectented EOL character may be lurking in `text` (in the CR + LF) case) and TB/RTB is configured to handle them differently.  Simple noting the expected length of `text` will (in)validate this concern.

---

Notes:
TB "the NewLine value is removed from the input buffer."
The value of NewLine in changeable.  The default is a line feed, (NewLine).